# HAProxy SSL connection error

Tags: ssl, cluster, haproxy, certificate

Brand new to setting up SSL with HAProxy and Litespeed load balancer, just generated my certificate using the .csr and am trying to have HAProxy terminate SSL before sending it to the web worker (Litespeed) for processing.

Here is the relevant portion of my HAProxy configuration:

```
> frontend frontend-web
>         bind x:80
>         bind x:443
> 
>         default_backend webworkers ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/folder/ prefer-server-ciphers ciphers RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA
```

HA-Proxy version 1.5-dev19 2013/06/17 (just updated, didn't work on 1.4)

Without using Cloudflare (I have already configured it with the keys) I get "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" and with Cloudflare I get 502 bad gateway.

Inside of my /etc/ssl/certs/folder I have the following:
gs_intermediate_ca.crt  x.crt  x.pem

The x.pem and x.crt are identical (is this supposed to be the case?)

In the HAProxy log I am seeing:
Sep  2 20:50:41 localhost.localdomain haproxy[6485]: 50.77.114.9:63791

> [02/Sep/2013:20:50:41.571] frontend-web frontend-web/
>   -1/-1/-1/-1/5 400 187 - - PR-- 58/58/0/0/0 0/0 ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out you need to compile HAProxy on version 1.5 with specific arguments to allow for SSL.